# Is it okay to thank someone using the phrase 'great of you'?

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

Is 'great of you' a proper phrase for thanking someone?

Answer (score 1):

No, "Great of you*" is not an commonly used expression.

You probably have that mixed up with some common expressions. Besides "Thank you" and "I appreciate it." you can say:

> Good of you./It's good of you to...

In British English, people also say:

> Good on you!

This is not used in American English.